# editting a variable but not directly assign it

Tags: javascript, jquery

First i want to apologize for my bad english,

I am creating a small game in jquery/javascript, but now i want to create some 'upgrades' but there's a small problem i'm having here. First of all i dont know how exactly but i need it something like this

```
var clicker = 1;

clicker.upgrade(value, text, content);
```

something like this and variable clicker from `(clicker).upgrade` should be editted. In upgrade there should be a function that calls the var (`clicker`) and edit the value's of the variables called clicker.

I need that for easy use and that i can edit clicker into something else.

Thank you for reading this

Comment: what are you 'upgrading' clicker to?

Comment: `Number.prototype.upgrade = function(value,text,content){}`?

Comment: ehm well yeah i need some kinda function to call it like this : variable.function(); but variable should be able to dynamically change i dont know if its object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Brad Christie suggested you can create an upgrade method on the Number object's prototype, so if you add this line:

```
Number.prototype.upgrade = function(a) {clicker = a}
```

then you can do this:

```
var clicker = 3;
clicker.upgrade(4); // Now clicker == 4
```

with that said, this is a hack, and a ugly one as well. For two reasons, first of all, because  you want to be careful about changing the prototypes of built-in objects. The main reason is that you might be overwriting native properties (or future properties you don't know of). NOTE: Adding properties to the Object.prototype is problematic in even more ways as well.
The other ugly bit about this hack is that the variable name (clicker) is hard coded into the upgrade function. Which will be an issue, if for example, you change clicker's name and forget to change it in the upgrade function.

If you are willing to have the value not be the variable itself but a property of clicker, meaning:

```
clicker.value
```

then we can solve this alot more elegantly:

```
var Clicker = function(initialValue){ // We create a Clicker constructor object
     this.value = initialValue
     this.upgrade = function(newValue){
         this.value = newValue;
     }
}

// Then we create an instance of the Clicker constructor, passing it an initial value of 3.
// Notice the difference in the constructor and the instance names (capital letter).
var clicker = new Clicker(3);

clicker.value; // It has an initial value of 3
clicker.upgrade(5);
clicker.value; // It's new value is now 5
```

You can, of course, create more instances of the Clicker object using the `new` keyword ( it is very important, don't forget it) or use the literal object notation to create a singleton if you don't need more than one instance:

```
var clicker = {
  value: 3,
  upgrade: function(newValue){
    this.value = newValue;
  }
}
clicker.value; // 3
clicker.upgrade(5);
clicker.value; // 5
```

Comment: i think that this would be the solution since i have to change multiple value's of multiple variable's, i can see this working thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a constructor + a prototype. Don't extend a built-in.

Very basic example:

```
 (function(){
    var Foo = function(arg){
  };
  Foo.prototype.upgrade = function(value, text, content){
    do something;
  };
  var baz = new Foo();
  var foobar = new Foo();
  baz.upgrade(a, b c);
  foobar.upgrade(d, e, f);
})();
```

Comment: wouldn't it be hard to edit the 'variable' clicker in my case ? in this way i can only see that i have to hardcode the variable to edit the value